# How can I group objects of a class, based on consecutive attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

We have a class Shift:

```
class Shift:
    def __init__(self, station, week, dayofweek, date):
        self.station = station
        self.week = week
        self.dayofweek = dayofweek
        self.date = date
```

and we have a sorted list (by 'date' of these shifts) of instances from this class. I want to group those shifts which have consecutive dates together and store the groups in a list at the end.

Input: 
`[Shift(date=1),Shift(date=2),Shift(date=4),Shift(date=5),Shift(date=6)]`

Output:`[[Shift(date=1),Shift(date=2)],[Shift(date=4),Shift(date=5),Shift(date=6)]]`

Comment: Some sample input and expected output please.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Hi, I'll edit my question and add sample inputs and outputs. thanks!

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it? Can you not simply write a loop over the input list, inspect the `date` attribute of each item and sort them into new lists accordingly?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Hi, my question is exactly how can I inspect the date attribute of each? I tried to get similar keys for consecutive items but I got errors.

Comment: You inspect the date attribute like any other attribute by using the `.` syntax, like `.date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the last `Shift` seen and then decide whether to add the next one to the last group or start a new group. Here's a paired down version:

```
class Shift:
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = date

    # some helpers to make other code clearer
    # and direct comparisons possible
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Shift({self.date})"

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.date < other.date

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.date - other.date

l = [Shift(1),Shift(6),Shift(5),Shift(4),Shift(2),Shift(9),Shift(7), Shift(0)] 

def groupNear(l):
    if not l:
        return l
    group = []
    current = l[0]

    for s in sorted(l):
        if s - current <= 1:
            group.append(s)
        else:
            yield group
            group = [s]
        current = s 
    yield group

list(groupNear(l))
```

Output:

```
[[Shift(0), Shift(1), Shift(2)],
 [Shift(4), Shift(5), Shift(6), Shift(7)],
 [Shift(9)]]
```